# checked value returns undefiend in Edit Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using states and props to make a CRUD table for my users ...
it's simple but I have a little issue in Edit function `fEdit();`
I don't know why it says the value of `isonline.checked` is undefiend :S
It works when I don't use my API and put requests and just push or remove data from the array ...
my Default value for booleans is false.

> **[This is my component](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-fire-bxy85?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**
>
> I used Postgres and wrote the users sql for u guys the file name is
>   `pg.sql`

**`fEdit();` FIXED**

> I created 2 inputs with isonline value, this fixed and  now `fSubmit()` for //update doesn't work and say isonline is not defined again ...
>   `err line:  datas[index].isonline = isonline;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have an input element with isonline ref in your JSX.You have isenable twice.

Comment: Is everything else seems okay?